# Can tr1::function swallow return values?

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1, boost-function

The boost::function [FAQ item 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/faq.html) specifically addresses the scenario I am interested in:

> Why are there workarounds for void
>   returns? C++ allows them! Void returns
>   are permitted by the C++ standard, as
>   in this code snippet:
>
> ```
> void f();
> void g() { return f(); }
> ```
>
> This is a valid usage of
>   boost::function because void returns
>   are not used. With void returns, we
>   would attempting to compile ill-formed
>   code similar to:
>
> ```
> int f();
> void g() { return f(); }
> ```
>
> In essence, not using void returns
>   allows boost::function to swallow a
>   return value. This is consistent with
>   allowing the user to assign and invoke
>   functions and function objects with
>   parameters that don't exactly match.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in VS2008:

```
int Foo();
std::tr1::function<void()> Bar = Foo;
```

This produces errors starting with:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xxcallfun(7) : error C2562: 'std::tr1::_Callable_fun<_Ty>::_ApplyX' : 'void' function returning a value
```

Is this a failing of the VS2008 TR1 implementation?  Does this work in VS2010?  Does TR1 address this capability?  How about C++0x?

Comment: `void g() { return f(); }` is allowed to support template code where the return type of the function might not be known in advance... it is still an error for `f()` to actually return a value if `g()` does not. Given this, I would not be surprised to find that the standards comittee elected to diverge from Boost's implementation in this regard, since it provides a more intuitive behavior. But since gcc *does* allow this behavior, I'm not positive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe tr1 addresses this issue.  [N1836](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf) (the latest tr1 draft) says:

> A function object f of type F is
>   Callable for argument types T1, T2,
>   ..., TN and a return type R, if, given
>   lvalues t1, t2, ..., tNoftypesT1, T2,
>   ..., TN,respectively,INVOKE(f, t1, t2,
>   ..., tN)is well-formed([3.3]) and, if R
>   is not void, convertible to R.

In your example R is void, and so the last part of the requirements for `Callable` (convertible to R) is ignored.

However it looks like C++0x (C++11) changes the rules.  In C++11 `Callable` is defined as `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` which is defined in [func.require] as requiring `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` to be implicitly convertible to R, with no exception for when R is void.  So in C++11, your example should fail.

Comment: Do you know if there is a rationale for this change/regression?  If not, it sounds like a defect.

Comment: This indeed sounds weird. No expression is implicitly convertible to `void`. Not even an expression of type `void` (according to clause 4 paragraph 3). One needs an explicit cast to convert things to `void`. I suppose that the intent is that only if the result type is different from `R`, then the expression is implicitly converted to `R`. Then the result could still have the type `void` when `R` is `void`. It's easy to be tricked by those paragraphs though, IMO :)